# RequireJs - why is Jquery injected and JSZip is not?

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs

I'm trying to understand how requireJs works, could somebody please explain to me, why in the following example:

http://plnkr.co/edit/HEDc8F19wICMy0zeGWpH?p=preview

More specifically here:

```
require(['ble'], function () {
  $('#someDiv').html(Ble.A());//This works fine

  var zip = new JSZip();//This fails with JSZip is not defined
  console.log(zip);
});
```

Jquery is defined, but JSZip is not? I also tried other combinations, but only one that seems to work is when I manually specify jszip in require array like this:

```
require(['jszip','ble'], function (JSZip) {
  $('#someDiv').html(Ble.A());

  var zip = new JSZip();
  console.log(zip);
});
```

I know that documentation states:

> The shim config only sets up code relationships. To load modules that
>   are part of or use shim config, a normal require/define call is
>   needed. Setting shim by itself does not trigger code to load.

But then - is jquery some kind of "special case" and I should normally, inject my dependencies manually even if they are specified in shim config section?

**ASWER:**

So it turns out jQuery is indeed a special case, and normally a manual injection of dependencies is required...

Comment: Yes, jQuery is a special case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look in the [source code of jQuery](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.js) you will find the following:

```
// Register as a named AMD module, since jQuery can be concatenated with other
// files that may use define, but not via a proper concatenation script that
// understands anonymous AMD modules. A named AMD is safest and most robust
// way to register. Lowercase jquery is used because AMD module names are
// derived from file names, and jQuery is normally delivered in a lowercase
// file name. Do this after creating the global so that if an AMD module wants
// to call noConflict to hide this version of jQuery, it will work.

// Note that for maximum portability, libraries that are not jQuery should
// declare themselves as anonymous modules, and avoid setting a global if an
// AMD loader is present. jQuery is a special case. For more information, see
// https://github.com/jrburke/requirejs/wiki/Updating-existing-libraries#wiki-anon

if ( typeof define === "function" && define.amd ) {
    define( "jquery", [], function() {
        return jQuery;
    });
}
```

This means that jQuery will - when required - define itself as `jquery`.

Answer (score 0):

```
require(['jszip','ble'], function (JSZip) {
```

In this above statement, it imports the jszip and returns a object as `JSZip`.

```
var zip = new JSZip();
```

Here that object is used. So with this code you did not get error.

Thus, For jszip, just require is not enough.